# Where is my Powerpoint template located?

Tags: templates, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I need to create a Powerpoint presentation based on our official template. I should be able to choose between a German and an English template. However, I have 3 templates; two templates are German and one is English. I cannot distinguish the two German templates, because they look the same and have an identical name.

[image: Powerpoint templates]

The official Powerpoint template directory is published via group policies. I looked up that directory (a network share) and there are only 2 templates: one German and one English.

I then used [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to see whether I have such a file on my local hard disk: there is none. (I'm running the tool as administrator)

How do I find out which item is the official one, located in the folder that's published via group policies? And how do I remove the other one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and set a filter for `Process Name`, `contains`, `Powerpnt`. This will record the activities of Powerpoint. Navigate to File/New and wait until the three entries are shown.

Then search for the name of the template and you'll find a Registry key access in

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Recent Templates\
```

Close Powerpoint, then delete the entries `Item x` and `Item Metadata x`. restart Powerpoint and the recent files should be gone.

You'll also notice that there aren't no entries any longer. The official templates do appear one section lower. So: don't use the ones at the top, they are just the recent files. Your official templates are here:

[image: Official templates]